# JQuery datepicker's button "behind" menu div

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, html, datepicker

I'm working on an MVC website.

I have a menu div at the top, and on a certain page there are text inputs with an added jquery datepicker, as seen in this picture:

[image]

When the mouse pointer is at the red circle, and I click, the calender should go to the previous month. What happens however, is the menu at the back gets clicked and not the calender (As you can see in the link on the bottom) and this causes a controller call and  a page redirect. I have tried fooling around with z-index on the divs but this does not solve the problem, as they are already indexed fine visually.

Does anyone know of an approach I can take on this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that all element z-Indexed are positionned ? I mean you have to specified the css attribute : `position` to `fixed`,`relative` or `absolute` on each elements that you want to order.

Comment: I fixed it. Just adding a z-index didn't work, but adding the !important keyword to it fixed the problem.

    .ui-datepicker { z-index: 10100 !important; }